# Is there an R function to calculate the required sample size using the Clopper-Pearson Confidence Interval?

Tags: r, sampling, poisson, sample-size

I need to determine the appropriate sample size to estimate p in a binomial process, using R. I see the package binomSamSize, but I do not see sample size determinations using Clopper-Pearson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `binomSamSize` pkg has a general purpose function binom.ciss, which allows you to use any confidence interval function from the `binom` pkg for the sample size determination. Hence, you can do Clopper-Pearson sample size determination easily using:

```
library(binomSamSize)
ciss.binom(p0=0.1, d=0.1, alpha=0.05, ci.fun=binom::binom.exact)
```